# How to pass ID of a table as parameter in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a stored procedure which is getting the days information employee was absent from office. I am passing ID of employee separately as parameter value to get the details of employee. What I want to do is to get all information of all employees at once without passing any value in parameter. I know it seems silly question but I am not able to think of anything right now maybe working for so long and am skipping basic thing to get what I want.

Here is the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE HRM.ProcRptEmployeeAbsentsDays
@empCode bigint, 
@dateFrom date,
@dateTo date
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, CalendarDate, (Status) Absents
    FROM ( 
    SELECT ID, 
    CASE 
        WHEN IsOffDay = 1 AND TimeIn1 IS NULL AND TimeOut1 IS NULL AND PreviousDayTimeIn IS NULL AND PreviousDayTimeOut IS NULL AND NextDayTimeIn IS NULL AND NextDayTimeOut IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN IsOffDay = 1 AND (PreviousDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR PreviousDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL) THEN 0
        WHEN IsPublicHoliday = 1 AND TimeIn1 IS NULL AND TimeOut1 IS NULL AND PreviousDayTimeIn IS NULL AND PreviousDayTimeOut IS NULL AND NextDayTimeIn IS NULL AND NextDayTimeOut IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN IsPublicHoliday = 1 AND (PreviousDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR PreviousDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL) THEN 0
        WHEN TimeIn1 IS NULL AND TimeOut1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END Status,
    CalendarDate
    FROM
    (
      SELECT 
      (SELECT ID FROM HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo Info WHERE Info.ID = @empCode) ID, CalendarDate, 
        CASE WHEN (SELECT CAST(DOJ AS DATE) FROM HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo Info WHERE Info.ID = @empCode)<CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) THEN 
        CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(dw,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)) = (SELECT OffDay1 FROM HRM.tbl_Shift WHERE ID = (SELECT ShiftCode FROM [dbo].[fnGetEmployeeShiftCode](CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @empCode))) THEN 1 
        WHEN DATENAME(dw,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)) = (SELECT OffDay2 FROM HRM.tbl_Shift WHERE ID = (SELECT ShiftCode FROM [dbo].[fnGetEmployeeShiftCode](CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @empCode))) THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END 
        ELSE 0 END 
        AS IsOffDay,
        CASE WHEN (SELECT CAST(DOJ AS DATE) FROM HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo Info WHERE Info.ID = @empCode)<CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) THEN 
        [dbo].[fnIsPublicHoliday](CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @empCode) 
        END AS IsPublicHoliday,
        PreviousDayTimeIn    = [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](1,DATEADD(DD, -1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @empCode, 1),
        TimeIn1    = [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](1,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @empCode, 1),
        NextDayTimeIn    = [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](1,DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @empCode, 1),

        PreviousDayTimeOut   = ISNULL(([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, -1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @empCode, 2)), ([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, -1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @empCode, 1))),

        TimeOut1   = ISNULL(([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @empCode, 2)), ([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @empCode, 1))),

        NextDayTimeOut   = ISNULL(([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @empCode, 2)), ([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @empCode, 1)))

      FROM [CalendarDates] 
      WHERE CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    )T
    )S
    WHERE Status = 1
END
GO
```

As you can see I have to provide the `@empCode` to get the information of each employee, I want to provide the ID from a table something like this `HRM.ProcRptEmployeeAbsentsDays (select id from hrm.tbl_employeeinfo), '2019-12-01', '2019-12-31'` but this seems not be the correct way so it's returning error. Can anyone guide me in the right direction ?

Comment: Do you really want all employees - in which case you don't need any parameter, just SELECT all employes. Or you want to pass a set of employee IDs (possibly a proper subset of all IDs) - which can be done via a table valued parameter.

Comment: BTW, looks like `@dateFrom` and `@dateTo` are not used (there are hard-coded values in your query).

Comment: Holy death by function overuse. You have so many function calls in this code it is truly scary. Some are scalar others are table functions. If you really want the values for every employee then turn this procedure into a table valued function. Then query the employee table and use a cross apply. But I would take a long hard look at this procedure and see if you can reduce the number of function calls by about 90% or more.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Yes for now I've hard coded dates but I am not able to cast out the `@empCode` here. I am sure I am messing with the query somewhere

Comment: @SeanLange I know it's messed up and I need to improve this like 100 times but for now I am just looking to get the details of all employees

Comment: Also, `CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)` is non-sargable. This alone will cause a full table scan (without even going into issues identified by @SeanLange).

Comment: Well the way to get data for all employees is to figure out how to get the data for a single employee. As slow as this is you might as well just through a cursor around the outside and go get lunch while it runs. Not trying to be snarky but seriously, you need to address this. If not now, when?

Comment: @SeanLange frankly speaking, Next month. At the moment I have a deadline to get the data and pass it to stakeholder who's on my nerves

Comment: I can't believe it isn't easier to create a calendar table of dates, calculate the status for all employees across each date and store in another table as a Cartesian product.  Then query the table straightaway.  If you had 50,000 employees, that's only 18M rows per year.

Comment: Well then in the name of getting it done right now wrap this with a cursor and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE HRM.ProcRptEmployeeAbsentsDays
@dateFrom date,
@dateTo date
AS
declare @minempcode int,@maxempcode int
set @minempcode=(select min(id) from hrm.tbl_employeeinfo)
set @maxempcode=(select max(id) from hrm.tbl_employeeinfo)
while(@minempcode<=@maxempcode)
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, CalendarDate, (Status) Absents
    FROM ( 
    SELECT ID, 
    CASE 
        WHEN IsOffDay = 1 AND TimeIn1 IS NULL AND TimeOut1 IS NULL AND PreviousDayTimeIn IS NULL AND PreviousDayTimeOut IS NULL AND NextDayTimeIn IS NULL AND NextDayTimeOut IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN IsOffDay = 1 AND (PreviousDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR PreviousDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL) THEN 0
        WHEN IsPublicHoliday = 1 AND TimeIn1 IS NULL AND TimeOut1 IS NULL AND PreviousDayTimeIn IS NULL AND PreviousDayTimeOut IS NULL AND NextDayTimeIn IS NULL AND NextDayTimeOut IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN IsPublicHoliday = 1 AND (PreviousDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR PreviousDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL) THEN 0
        WHEN TimeIn1 IS NULL AND TimeOut1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END Status,
    CalendarDate
    FROM
    (
      SELECT 
      (SELECT ID FROM HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo Info WHERE Info.ID = @minempCode) ID, CalendarDate, 
        CASE WHEN (SELECT CAST(DOJ AS DATE) FROM HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo Info WHERE Info.ID = @minempCode)<CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) THEN 
        CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(dw,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)) = (SELECT OffDay1 FROM HRM.tbl_Shift WHERE ID = (SELECT ShiftCode FROM [dbo].[fnGetEmployeeShiftCode](CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @minempcode))) THEN 1 
        WHEN DATENAME(dw,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)) = (SELECT OffDay2 FROM HRM.tbl_Shift WHERE ID = (SELECT ShiftCode FROM [dbo].[fnGetEmployeeShiftCode](CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @minempcode))) THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END 
        ELSE 0 END 
        AS IsOffDay,
        CASE WHEN (SELECT CAST(DOJ AS DATE) FROM HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo Info WHERE Info.ID = @minempCode)<CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) THEN 
        [dbo].[fnIsPublicHoliday](CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @minempcode) 
        END AS IsPublicHoliday,
        PreviousDayTimeIn    = [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](1,DATEADD(DD, -1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @minempCode, 1),
        TimeIn1    = [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](1,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @minempcode, 1),
        NextDayTimeIn    = [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](1,DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @minempcode, 1),

        PreviousDayTimeOut   = ISNULL(([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, -1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @minempcode, 2)), ([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, -1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @minempcode, 1))),

        TimeOut1   = ISNULL(([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @minempcode, 2)), ([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @minempcode, 1))),

        NextDayTimeOut   = ISNULL(([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @minempcode, 2)), ([dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @minempcode, 1)))

      FROM [CalendarDates] 
      WHERE CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    )T
    )S
    WHERE Status = 1
set @minempcode=@minempcode+1;
END
GO
```

I have added two variables `@minempcode,@maxempcode` and used while loop on your `min(id)` and `max(id)` from `hrm.tbl_employeeinfo`. If your id's are not in serial order then add an identity column based on ascending order of `ID` and take it's `min` and `max` value and then loop on it. Hope it will work!